# Baby Rudin Chap. 6, Prob. 7(a) Definition of $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

**Problem**

> Suppose $f$ is a real function on $(0,1]$ and $f$ is Riemann integrable ($f \in \mathscr{R}$) on $[c,1]$ for every $c >0$. Define
>   $$ \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = \lim_{c \rightarrow 0^\color{red}{+}} \int_c^1 f(x)\, dx$$
>   if this limit exists and is finite.
>
> If $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[0,1]$, show that this definition of the integral agrees with the old one.

The old one is the usual Daraboux integral of $f$ on $[0,1]$. I believe I completed the problem but I afraid I overlooked something since my proof seems too simple:

**My work**

Pick any $\epsilon >0$.

> *Claim:* $\exists\ \delta >0$ s.t. $\forall\ c \in [0,1]$
>   $$\delta > c > 0 \implies \bigg| \int_0^1 f(x)\, dx - \int_0^c f(x)\, dx \bigg| < \epsilon$$

For $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[0,1]$, $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ by definition. $\exists \ M > 0$ s.t. $\forall\ x \in [0,1]$, $|f(x)|< M$.

Take $\delta = \epsilon/M$. $\delta >0$. Pick any $c \in (0,\delta)$.

Since $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[0,1]$, $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[0,c]$ and $[c,1]$ and we have

$$\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx = \int_0^c f(x)\, dx + \int_c^1 f(x)\, dx \implies \int_0^1 f(x)\, dx- \int_c^1 f(x)\, dx = \int_0^c f(x)\, dx $$

$$\bigg|\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx- \int_c^1 f(x)\, dx\bigg| = \bigg|\int_0^c f(x)\, dx\bigg| \leq M(c - 0) < M\delta = M(\epsilon/M) = \epsilon $$

Thus the claim is established. From the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, we have

$$ \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = \lim_{c \rightarrow 0^+} \int_c^1 f(x)\, dx$$

But the process seems too smooth...Other problems in this book is never that easy. Am I overlooking something or going in a completely wrong direction?

Comment: This is the approach I would take; I think your proof is ok too